# How to rollback jQuery Update module?

Tags: javascript

I accidentally update jQuery version from 1.5.2 to 1.82 using Drupal's jQuery update module.  Is there any way to rollback the update and go back to my 1.5.2 version?

Changing the option exists only in the dev version. So I downloaded the dev version and set it to 1.5.2. However, now, I am getting this message:

> jQuery could not be replaced with an uncompressed version of 1.4.4, because jQuery 1.5.2 is running on the site.

Don't know what that means, because I am not trying to run 1.4.4.

Comment: There is an option to select the version(1.5.2/1.7/1.8) in _admin/config/development/jquery_update_.

Comment: uninstall module :)

Comment: @Serjas: Changing the option exists only in the dev version.  So I downloaded the dev version and set it to 1.5.2.  However, now, I am getting this message: jQuery could not be replaced with an uncompressed version of 1.4.4, because jQuery 1.5.2 is running on the site.  Don't know what that means, because I am not trying to run 1.4.4.

Comment: if thats the case , follow @monymirza . Uninstall and then do a fresh start. Jquary update wont break any of your existing code by uninstalling

Answer (score 1):

The following error comes from the Devel module. In the case you'd like to get rid of the message on every page, you should go to the Devel settings page (/admin/config/development/devel) and disable the *Use uncompressed jQuery* option.

> jQuery could not be replaced with an uncompressed version of 1.4.4, because jQuery 1.7.1 is running on the site.

To rollback the module, you need to disable and uninstall the old module, and install another one.

#### Source

[This is on EVERY single page in my installation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1814146).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and then do a fresh start.

jQuery update won't break any of your existing code by uninstalling.